# How to make choices based on the model? - Models aren't loaded yet. FK issue (seems to be)

Tags: django, django-models

Read all topics at StackOverflow and internet - no luck.

```
# admindivisions.models
class Countries(models.Model):
    osm_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    population = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    iso3166_1 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    iso3166_1_a2 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    iso3166_1_a3 = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'admindivisions_countries'
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

class CountriesTranslations(models.Model):
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=81, blank=True, db_index=True)
    formal_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Details of Country')
    lang_group = models.ForeignKey(LanguagesGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Language of Country',
                                   null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'admindivisions_countries_translations'
        verbose_name = 'Country Translation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries Translations'

# profiles.models
from admindivisions.models import CountriesTranslations, Countries

class AbstractProfile(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = ()

    if (Languages.objects.model._meta.db_table in connection.introspection.table_names()):
        # Just for test - This executes without any errors
        CountriesTranslations.objects.filter(common_name="USA")

        for country in Countries.objects.filter(status=1).exclude(iso3166_1='', iso3166_1_a2=''):
            # Just for test - Also executes ok
            CountriesTranslations.objects.get(common_name="USA")

            # Makes problem (seems to be because of FK)                
            country_name = CountriesTranslations.objects.get(country=country)
            COUNTRY_CHOICES += ((country.id, country_name),)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, verbose_name=_('country'), choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=30)
    info = models.TextField(_('information'), max_length=500, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/sportland/src/profiles/models.py", line 76, in <module>
    class AbstractProfile(models.Model):
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/sportland/src/profiles/models.py", line 109, in AbstractProfile
    country_name = CountriesTranslations.objects.get(country=country)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 796, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 814, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1227, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1253, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1133, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1019, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1308, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 111, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/antonio/www/sportland/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

This happens if I want to execute any `manage.py`s command.

Coming from few tests above I can guess the problem is due to ForeignKey. How to fix it?

Django 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn't do any logic like that at class level. Obviously you can't query the models until they are all fully loaded.

I don't understand what you are trying to do there, but you should move it into a method.

Comment: I want to make choices. I added appropriate pieces of code to show how I wanted to do that. After your answer I also found how to solve it via `form`. Is it possible to implement it somehow in models or `form` is my way?

Comment: You should do that in the form where to want to use these choices, at the point where you instantiate it.